# Haskell syntax, binding file contents to variables

Tags: function, haskell, if-statement, syntax

The main idea of the code is this I load an expression from a file which has only 1 line like `100 + a + (x ^ 2)`

I want to load it in a function and check if it's ok (so it is not like `)) + 5 2 a **`). First I want to say that I know my checks are not covering all type of mistakes but we have to check only for some mistakes. First here is the code

```
main = do  
   contents <- readFile "file.txt"  
   let stringToCheck <- line contents
   checkIfProper filter (/=' ') stringToCheck
```

As you can see I am really new to Haskell and I would like this to work and I would fix it step by step. I think logically it is fine and there are only syntax mistakes that I can't understand.

My first question is at the begining of the main I load from a file.txt this file has only 1 line and I take it in the stringToCheck and then I want to use filter on it to remove all spaces but this doesn't work. If I call the filter on a string I write down at the moment it's fine but when I load it from the file it has problems I guess I don't take the line properly so how to do this?

How do you take a string properly from a file and use it as a variable in other function?

Comment: You lost some formatting when posting. Haskell is format-sensitive, so this turned your code into gunk. Please fix.

Comment: I have not tried to read your code, but some immediately available low hanging fruit is: The `Bool`s are `False` and `True`, not `false` and `true`.

Comment: … also, it's not `'elem'` - infix notation uses backticks. And your guards  don't parse at all. Have you looked at a Haskell introduction yet? I don't mean to be rude, but you seem to be trying to chew off too much at once here.

Comment: Also you seem to be having trouble leaving imperative programming behind. You shouldn't be using do blocks everywhere. Write lots of small, simple functions instead of one huge do-everything function.

Comment: Also, you don't use let statements at the top level, nor do you use `<-` with let but rather `=`.

Comment: You seem to have a habit of posting a question and then going away for a number of hours. Things tend to move fairly quickly on Stack Overflow, and if you stick around you can respond to comments like _"You lost some formatting when posting. Haskell is format-sensitive, so this turned your code into gunk. Please fix."_ and thus get help with your actual problem sooner.

Comment: I can't see what I lost I mean I see everything and I don't know which part you can't. @gspr you are right I am trying to chew off too much at once that is the case.

Comment: I will try to divade the problem on several smaller ones so I am editing the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
main = do  
   contents <- readFile "file.txt"
```

So far everything fine. You've read in the file in `IO`, and used the `do`-block syntax with `<-` correctly. For everything underneath, `contents` is a `String` variable that holds the contents of the file.

```
   let stringToCheck <- line contents
```

Here, you do *not* need this special assignment syntax: at this point as I said, `contents` is a "pure" value, so anything you use it for is purely functional and you can use ordinary `=`. That's always done in `let` blocks. So...

```
   let stringToCheck = line contents
```

Well, that doesn't work because there's no `line` function. There is `lines`, which splits up a text in a list of strings, each representing a line; to retrieve the first one use

```
   let stringToCheck = head $ lines contents
```

but if the file only *has* one line then this is equivalent to simply `stringToCheck = contents`.

```
   checkIfProper filter (/=' ') stringToCheck
```

Now, here is suppose you mean `checkIfProper (filter (/=' ') stringToCheck)`: the function `checkIfProper` takes just a single argument, but if you just write out a composite expression that is misparsed as a couple of different arguments, i.e. `checkIfProper filter (/=' ') stringToCheck` actually means what in un-curried languages would be written `checkIfProper(filter, (/=' '), stringToCheck)`. I don't think you mean that!

The idiomatic way of writing it in Haskell is

```
   checkIfProper $ filter (/=' ') stringToCheck
```

The resulting `main` might still not compile: the result of `checkIfProper` needs to have type `IO ()` so you can simply append it to a `do` block as in `main`, but apparently it has type `String -> Bool`. Perhaps you want the result printed out, that's done with

```
   print . checkIfProper $ filter (/=' ') stringToCheck
```

---

In case you're not familiar with `.` and `$`: you can read an expression like

```
 f . g . h $ x + y
```

as

```
 f (g (h (x + y)))
```

Comment: But when I try to load the file in WinCHCi it says " parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)" and I am only doing the part of loading and filtering the string.

Comment: Well, then you probably have incorrect indentation, as the compiler suggests!

Comment: I can't format the code in the comments at all but I will try :
    `import System.IO  main = do` 
    `contents <- readFile "av.txt"`  

    `let stringToCheck = contents`

    `filter (/=' ') stringToCheck` 
 

I am sorry if the first time it does not format as it has to

Comment: I found the problem I am really sorry for all the problems and the spam I made around this. I will be more careful next time and will post my next question better.